# Logging and Error handling in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I have a website running now. I have to implement some logging routines as well as 
some handler for unhandeled exceptions. I was looking at ELMAH also which seems good to me.
I need something very light and easy to use. Can someone recommend any other option I can choose from.

Thanks
Parminder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

[log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

[ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx)